# keep TextLabel for tableviewcell at top

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using `UITableView` in my project. i am increasing and decreasing the height of `UITableView` cell on the continuous taps. In other words i am toggling the height of `UITableViewCell` on taps. Now i want to keep the `UITableViewCell` `textLabel` at the same place which is at the top. But when i increase the height of `UITableViewCell` the `textLabel` come in the middle of the cell.

To avoid this is am using `sizeToFit` for `cell.textLabel` but it not working... any help...

Comment: Did you try using constraints? It should work. Use constraints to set up the distance of the textLabel from the textLabel to the top of the cell

Comment: i am using the default textLabel which is actually a property of UITableViewCell. I am not adding a separate textLabel on the contectview of the UITableviewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is add Auto-Layout constraints to the default TextLabel programmatically. I would pin it from the leading edge, trailing edge, and bottom edge of the Superview (in this case being the cell).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

and don't do the size to fit. What this will do is change the distance from the bottom of your label to the bottom of the cell. In other words, it will keep the distance from the top constant.